# How do I enable tab tips in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, bashrc, chroot

I am working under debian squeeze. I always install packages such way:

```
sudo apt-g(Tab pressed) i(Tab pressed) aria(Tab pressed)
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

I have installed chroot squeeze to test my deb packages to prevent demage to main system. But such tips (Tab) doesn't work there. I think I can enable this tips in .bashrc. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant section in the debian default `bashrc` is

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

The file sourced there is part of the `bash-completion` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/bash_completion
bash-completion: /etc/bash_completion
```